# Maven plugin compiles fine but can't find class during execution

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, slf4j

I am stuck with the following Maven problem.

Basically, I have two projects. Project A is a Maven plugin and project B is using it.

Project A `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.github.martinschneider</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Project B `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.github.martinschneider</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.martinschneider</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When executing `mvn demo:demo` on project B, the mojo starts executing but then I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal my.group:my-maven-plugin:1.2.3:some-goal (default-cli) on project my-project: Execution default-cli of goal my.group:my-maven-plugin:1.2.3:some-goal failed: A required class was missing while executing io.github.martinschneider:demo-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:demo: org/slf4j/event/Level
```

The core message of the error is:

```
A required class was missing [...] : org/slf4j/event/Level
```

The log and stacktrace also include:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: package.SomeMojo java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/event/Level
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.event.Level
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
```

It boils down to `org.slf4j.event.Level` not being found on the classpath which is strange because it is in `slf4j-api` which is both an explicit and a transitive (via `slf4j-core`) dependency in the plugin.

However, for some reason it is not included in the class realm:

```
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>io.martinschneider.github:demo-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   Included: io.martinschneider.github:demo-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.25
...
```

`slf4j-simple` is in the list, `slf4j-api` is not.

A few lines earlier:

```
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=121223, ConflictMarker.markTime=606293, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=72, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=74295, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=819750, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=45, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1909563, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=70, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=68369892, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=3575054}
[DEBUG] io.martinschneider.github:demo-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.25:compile
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
...
```

Here, both `slf4j-simple` and `slf4j-api` are included.

The problem only occurs when I explicitly use the affected class `org.slf4j.event.Level` in my plugin code. If I remove any *explicit* usage of it everything works fine.

I'm using Maven 3.5.2 and Java 11.

I don't know if this is a problem with SLF4J or a more general problem with Maven or just an unlucky combination of events.

What I've tried:

- deleted and re-populated my Maven repo (to rule out corrupted JAR files)
- tried different versions of SLF4J
- explicitly added `slf4j-api` under `<pluginDepdendencies>`
- used Java 8 (instead of 11)

**UPDATE**
I've created a demo project to reproduce this error: https://github.com/martinschneider/stackoverflow_53757567

Comment: In the `pom.xml` of Project B `org.slf4j.slf4j-api` is mentioned *twice*, is that a mistake while copying to StackOverflow?

Comment: Good point, yes that was a mistake. Only `slf4j-api` is specified in project B.

Comment: First how do you knew that there had been corrupted JAR files? Second why do you need SLF4j? You can simply do `getLog().debug("xxx")` or `getLog().info("XXX")` ...

Comment: My use-case for Level is a bit more complex than the (dummy one) in the example. I have a workaround, of course, but this error is so strange that I would want to know what's at the root of it.

Comment: For the corrupted files, I don't think there were. It just happened in the past and the error was somewhat similar (classes couldn't be found). So, to rule that out (and because I'd only run out of ideas), I tried with a fresh Maven repo too.

Comment: what happened when you tried other slf4j versions? do you have the same problem?

Comment: Did you try changing the order of the dependencies in the pom file? Also if you are using eclipse check the `Dependency Hierarchy`.

Comment: This appears to have been reported as [MNG-6618](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6618), fixed in Maven 3.6.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [comment in MNG-5845 issue for similar problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5845?focusedCommentId=14941189&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14941189):

> The problem comes from the fact that we are exporting the slf4j-api artefact, thus plugins cannot use their own version but we forgot to export the content of the package org/slf4j/helpers. Thus the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter`

`slf4j-api` is one of the special dependencies exported by maven core however `org.sfl4j.event` package isn't exported. Looking [at Maven master](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/a2b800de32cdb9adc1e64a43a0fc32e3ba878103/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/extension.xml#L119), currently the following packages are exported:

```
<!-- SLF4J -->
<exportedPackage>org.slf4j.*</exportedPackage>
<exportedPackage>org.slf4j.spi.*</exportedPackage>
<exportedPackage>org.slf4j.helpers.*</exportedPackage>
```

Because of above you won't be able to access classes from `org.sfl4j.event` package during your plugin execution. You can compile the plugin code since the compile classpath is different than runtime classpath. This can be confirmed by removing the second log statement and related `import` statement, the plugin will execute just fine which proves that SLF4J JARs aren't corrupted:

```
[INFO] ---------------< io.github.martinschneider:demo-project >---------------
[INFO] Building demo-project 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- demo-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:demo (default-cli) @ demo-project ---
[INFO] Hello world!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

You can either open a new issue in Maven project and include a new export statement or implement plugin logging with standard `getLog()` method as per [A Simple Mojo guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html):

```
@Mojo(name = "demo")
public class DemoMojo extends AbstractMojo {

  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    getLog().info("Hello world!");
  }

}
```